# $match after $lookup - specify a pipeline at lookup stage not helping

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection for products and orders. I'm doing an aggregation on orders - where orders are active and the product is active as well. Below is my aggregation pipeline on orders collection:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'isActive': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'product_masters', 
      'as': 'productData', 
      'let': {
        'isinNo': '$isinNo'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$and': [
                {
                  '$eq': [
                    '$isinNo', '$$isinNo'
                  ]
                }, {
                  '$eq': [
                    '$productStatus', 1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Basically the isinNo is a common field and isActive (on orders) & productStatus (on product_masters) indicate whether both of them are active.
However, I am getting active orders in output, but it also includes inactive products, i.e. where productStatus is not equal to 1.
Can you please help me understand where it is going wrong?

Comment: in the lookup stage, its only doing filter document because no relation with `order`. you need one more match, please put an example for order and product to make us easier to understand the case

Comment: That aggregation appears to work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/w3rjGGRvulv Do you have sample data that can demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Joe, in your dataset of product_master where isinNo is not 1, it still returns 1 order where productData is []. I didn't want this record in result. So, then what I did is to add a match expression again to filter out where productData is []. With this my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The objective of getting only active orders was solved by adding another match condition to the pipeline checking if the productData received from lookup stage is not [].